# Convert number to date in php

Tags: php

I need to convert a variable

```
$date = 20130521201511
```

to

```
$date = 2013-05-21 20:15:11
```

however I am not quite sure how to do so.

Comment: take a look at date() in php

Comment: you can use `substr` function. http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php

Comment: **Note**: The `createFromFormat()` function, is available for PHP 5.3+ only, in regards to some of the answers given below. *Thought you'd need to know that*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php
    $d = 20130521201511;
    $x = substr($d, 0, 4) .'-'. substr($d, 4,2) .'-'. substr($d,6,2) .' '. substr($d,8,2) .':'. substr($d,10,2) .':'. substr($d,12,2);
    echo $x;
?>
```

Answer (score 6):

This is achievable using the [DateTime](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) class.

```
<?php
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat("YmdHis","20130521201511");

var_dump($date);
```

https://eval.in/33909

Look closely at the documentation of the [createFromFormat](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php) method to be sure to use the correct format parameters.

Answer (score 3):

Use DateTime

```
php $oldDate= 20130521201511;
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('YmdGis', $oldDate);
  echo $date->format('Y-m-d G:i:s');
```

Comment: The user must be careful if G or H is needed for the hour.

Comment: @Bgi with `createFromFormat()`, they don't (but with `format()` they do).

Comment: @salathe How do you know they don't? The one (s)he gave is just an example. You'd need to see other examples to know.

Comment: `G` and `H` do *exactly* the same thing in `DateTime::createFromFormat()`.

Answer (score -1):

Just Try this
date("Y-m-d H:i:s", 1388516401);

The logic behind this conversion from date to an integer is explained in strotime in php.net.

It is the number of seconds since January 1 1970 00:00:00 UTC.

Printing echo strtotime("1970-01-01 00:00:00") gives you 0.
Printing echo strtotime("1970-01-01 00:00:01") gives you 1.

Comment: The question is not about converting epoch seconds, he has a string he needs converted in a particular format...